# Showing $\hat{A} \otimes_{A} M \cong \hat{M}$ when $M$ is a finitely generated free $A$-module.

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I had a reading question on Proposition 10.13 from Atiyah-MacDonald. The proposition is the following

PROPOSITION. For any ring $A$, if $M$ is finitely-generated, $\hat{A} \otimes_{A} M \rightarrow \hat{M}$ is surjective. If, moreover, $A$ is Noetherian then $\hat{A} \otimes_{A} M \rightarrow \hat{M}$ is an isomorphism.

I am having trouble with the simple case of the proof, where $M \cong A^{n}$ for a Noetherian ring $A$. Here $\hat{A}$ and $\hat{M}$ denote $\mathfrak{a}$-adic completions where $\mathfrak{a}$ is some ideal of $A$. The map $\hat{A} \otimes_{A} M \rightarrow \hat{M}$ is the map 
$$\hat{A} \otimes_{A} M \rightarrow \hat{A} \otimes_{\hat{A}} \hat{M} \cong \hat{M}$$
I am a bit lost on where to start, any help or hints would be appreciated. I may be missing something basic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must keep in mind Proposition 10.12: If

$$0 \to M' \to M \to M'' \to 0$$

is an exact sequence of $A$ modules and $\hat{M}', \hat{M}, \hat{M}''$ are their ${\mathfrak a}$-adic completions then

$$0 \to \hat{M}' \to \hat{M} \to \hat{M}'' \to 0$$

is exact too.
This gives you first $\widehat{A^n} = \hat{A}^n$ by considering the sequence

$$0 \to A^{n-1} \to A^n \to A \to 0$$

and its completions inductively over $n$.

The general case is done explicitly in Atiyah-Macdonald.

Comment: This looks like what I seem to be looking for. Thanks

Comment: Let me add, that it is necessary to use, that the sequence $0 \to A^{n-1} \to A^n \to A \to 0$ is split and its completion, as a functor is split too.

Comment: When you say split do you mean that there is the map $A^{n} \rightarrow A^{n-1}$ which is identity with respect to the composition $A^{n-1} \rightarrow A^{n} \rightarrow A^{n-1}$. In which case, apply the functor, we obtain $\hat{A^{n-1}} \oplus \hat{A} \cong \hat{A^{n}}$

Comment: Yes, and there is an injective map $\phi:A \to A^n$ with $\pi \phi = 1_A$ where $\pi:A^n \to A$ is the surjection from the sequence.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the help, I should familiarize myself with the Splitting Lemma soon. Thanks again.